# Using ArgumentParser with Swift concurrency

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency, swift-argumentparser

I am using [`ArgumentParser`](https://www.swift.org/blog/argument-parser/) package for command-line parsing and want to use it with an `async` API of Swift concurrency:

```swift
struct Foo: ParsableCommand {
    @Argument(
        help: "File to be parsed. If not present, parses stdin.",
        transform: URL.init(fileURLWithPath:)
    )
    var file: URL?

    mutating func run() async throws {
        let handle: FileHandle
        if let file {
            handle = try .init(forReadingFrom: file)
        } else {
            handle = .standardInput
        }

        for try await line in handle.bytes.lines {
            // do something with each line
        }

        try handle.close()
    }
}
```

But when I do this, I always see the “USAGE” text:

```
USAGE: foo [<file>]

ARGUMENTS:
  <file>                  File to be parsed. If not present, parses stdin.

OPTIONS:
  -h, --help              Show help information.
```

I get no compilation errors, but I always see the “USAGE” text whether I supply a parameter or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the use of `ParsableCommand` in conjunction with `run() async throws`.

Use `AsyncParsableCommand` instead. As its [documentation](https://swiftpackageindex.com/apple/swift-argument-parser/1.2.2/documentation/argumentparser/asyncparsablecommand) says:

> To use `async`/`await` code in your commands’ `run()` method implementations, follow these steps:
>
> 1. For the root command in your command-line tool, declare conformance to `AsyncParsableCommand`, whether or not that command uses asynchronous code.
> 2. Apply the `@main` attribute to the root command. (Note: If your root command is in a `main.Swift` file, rename the file to the name of the command.)
> 3. For any command that needs to use asynchronous code, declare conformance to `AsyncParsableCommand` and mark the `run()` method as `async`. No changes are needed for subcommands that don’t use asynchronous code.

Unfortunately, while the broader [documentation](https://swiftpackageindex.com/apple/swift-argument-parser/1.2.2/documentation/argumentparser) makes an occasional reference to supporting `async`, you have to dig into the code samples (specifically, [`count-lines`](https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser/tree/main/Examples/count-lines)) or pour through the entire class library to stumble across `AsyncParsableCommand`.

So, use `AsyncParsableCommand` with `async` rendition of `run`:

```swift
import ArgumentParser

@main
struct Foo: AsyncParsableCommand {
    @Argument(
        help: "File to be parsed. If not present, parses stdin.",
        transform: URL.init(fileURLWithPath:)
    )
    var file: URL?

    mutating func run() async throws {
        let handle: FileHandle
        if let file {
            handle = try .init(forReadingFrom: file)
        } else {
            handle = .standardInput
        }

        for try await line in handle.bytes.lines {
            // do something with each line
        }

        try handle.close()
    }
}
```

But, unfortunately, if you accidentally use `async` rendition of `run` with `ParsableCommand`, it compiles without error but just produces the “USAGE” text whenever you run it, without any diagnostic information about *why* it is not working.

In short, `ParsableCommand` requires a non-`async` rendition of `run`. The `async` rendition requires `AsyncParsableCommand`.

Comment: FWIW, I’ve posted [an issue](https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser/issues/561) in the `ArgumentParser` repo, suggesting making `AsyncParsableCommand` a little more easily discovered and adding some error message if you have a mismatch between `ParsableCommand`/`AsyncParsableCommand` and the associated `run`.